# "one" application ID in Azure SSO for "multiple" targets?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

I wonder if there is a way to add within the Application manifest file (or any other way) to have two (more) "targets" share the same Application ID.

If I register a new app - the appID is new.

Problem is that we have one solution that is configured for SSO but it runs on two domains - for managing languages (as what you see and can do depends on where you log in).

We have somedomain.xa for language XA and somedomain.yz for language YZ. But there are certain URL arguments that *** up the situation as

somedomain.xa --> rewrite --> somedomain.xa/companyID=100&lang=xa
somedomain.yz --> rewrite --> somedomain.yz/companyID=100&lang=xa

And the registration inside the solution is to use company ID, find the AppID from a DB table and then perform the handshake and authentication process. And if I register both domains on same ID, the SSO solution throws error.

Thus my "problem" - of there is a way out?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it looks like you have *one registered application* (one Application Id) that runs under the context of one Azure AD tenant, and you want to use this one application to redirect use to either one of the two different domains you have - is this correct?

If this is the case, what you need to do is just configure multiple redirect URLs for this one Application Registration information in portal.azure.com - https://somedomain.xa/page and https://somedomain.xa/page - then use set the Redirect URL parameter when requesting the authentication challenge - in your case as you detect user's language.